# Create new columns based on splitting string other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have used **re.search** to get strings of **uniqueID** from larger strings.
ex:

```py
import re

string= 'example string with this uniqueID: 300-350'
combination = '(\d+)[-](\d+)' 
m = re.search(combination, string)
print (m.group(0))

Out: '300-350'
```

I have created a dataframe with the **UniqueID** and the **Combination** as columns.

```py
    uniqueID    combinations
0   300-350     (\d+)[-](\d+)
1   off-250     (\w+)[-](\d+)
2   on-stab     (\w+)[-](\w+)
```

And a dictionary **meaning_combination** relating the combination with the variable meaning it represents:

```
meaning_combination={'(\\d+)[-](\\d+)': 'A-B',
 '(\\w+)[-](\\d+)': 'C-A',
 '(\\w+)[-](\\w+)': 'C-D'}
```

I want to create new columns for each variable (A, B, C, D) and fill them with their corresponding values.

the final result should look like this:

```py
    uniqueID    combinations   A    B   C     D
0   300-350     (\d+)[-](\d+)  300  350 
1   off-250     (\w+)[-](\d+)       250       off
2   on-stab     (\w+)[-](\w+)           stab  on
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that an item is either a sequence of digits, or a sequence of *non*-digits?

Comment: it can either be digit-digit, digit-nondigit, nondigit-nondigit

Comment: What have you tried in attempting to create the new columns aside from the regex search?

Comment: Nothiing actually, but the regex search found all my different combinations so I didn't look further. My issue is with dividing the uniqueID that I found using the regex search, based on a dictionary relating the different regex search combination to the variable values

Comment: To create the new columns I was thinking of doing something like gather all the unique variable names (A, B, C, D) and create new columns.  Then subset the dataframe based on the combinations, and then split the unique ID into its variables based upon the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix your regexes to:

```
meaning_combination={'(\d+-\d+)': 'A-B',
 '([^0-9\W]+\-\d+)': 'C-A',
 '([^0-9\W]+\-[^0-9\W]+)': 'C-D'}
```

To capture the full group instead of having three capturing groups.

I.e. `(300-350, 300, 350)` --> `(300-350)`

You don't need to have extra two capturing groups because if a specific pattern is satisfied then you know what the positions of the word or digit characters are (based on how you defined the pattern) and you can split by `-` to access them individually.

I.e.:

```
str = 'example string with this uniqueID: 300-350'
values = re.findall('(\d+-\d+)', str)
>>>['300-350']
#first digit char:
values[0].split('-')[0]
>>>'300'
```

If you use this way, you can loop over dictionary keys and list of strings and test if the pattern is satisfied in the string. If it's satisfied (`len(re.findall(pattern, string)) != 0`), then grab the corresponding dictionary value for the key and split it and split the match and assign `dictionary_value.split('-')[0] : match[0].split('-')[0]` and `dictionary_value.split('-')[1] : match[0].split('-')[1]` in a new dictionary that your creating in the loop - also assign unique id to the full match value and combination to the matched pattern. Then use pandas to make a Dataframe.

Altogether:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

stri= ['example string with this uniqueID: 300-350', 'example string with this uniqueID: off-250', 'example string with this uniqueID: on-stab']

meaning_combination={'(\d+-\d+)': 'A-B',
 '([^0-9\W]+\-\d+)': 'C-A',
 '([^0-9\W]+\-[^0-9\W]+)': 'C-D'}

values = [{'Unique ID': re.findall(x, st)[0], 'Combination': x, y.split('-')[0] : re.findall(x, st)[0].split('-')[0], y.split('-')[1] : re.findall(x, st)[0].split('-')[1]} for st in stri for x, y in meaning_combination.items() if len(re.findall(x, st)) != 0]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values)

#just to sort it in order since default is alphabetical 
col_val = ['Unique ID', 'Combination', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: col_val.index(x) ), axis=1)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Unique ID             Combination    A    B    C     D
0   300-350               (\d+-\d+)  300  350  NaN   NaN
1   off-250        ([^0-9\W]+\-\d+)  250  NaN  off   NaN
2   on-stab  ([^0-9\W]+\-[^0-9\W]+)  NaN  NaN   on  stab
```

Also, note, I think you have a typo in your expected output because you have:
`'(\\w+)[-](\\d+)': 'C-A'`

which would match `off-250`, but in your final result you have:

```
    uniqueID    combinations   A    B   C     D
1   off-250     (\w+)[-](\d+)       250       off
```

When based on your key this should be in `C` and `A`.